# ¿Cómo debo terminar mi estructura de control para que me permita volver al menú anterior?

Tags: java

necesito terminar el bucle, si la respuesta a la pregunta ¿otra venta? es No, debe volver al menu anterior ( salir del bucle)

```
            do {
                try
                {
                    continua = false;
                    //while venta = 1
                    System.out.println(" Cantidad de boletos a comprar:) ");
                    compra1 = Entrada.nextInt(); 
                }
                catch(InputMismatchException ime)
                { 
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.err.println("se permiten caracteres numericos");
                    Entrada.next(); continua = true; 
                }
            } while (continua);
            
            contador1 = 1;
            
            do {
                System.out.println(" Elija número de butaca: ");
                Asignacion = Entrada.nextInt();
                error1 = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) 
                    {
                         if (Sala1[i][j] == Asignacion) 
                         { 
                              posicion1 = error1;      
                              fila = i;  
                              columna = j; 
                         } 
                         error1++; 
                     } 
                 }
                 if (posicion1 >= 1) 
                 { 
                     Sala1[fila][columna] = 99; 
                 }
                 else 
                 {
                     System.out.println("Butaca restringida");
                 }
                 contador1++;
            } while (contador1 <= compra1);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
            {
                System.out.println();
                for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) 
                { 
                    System.out.print("[" + Sala1[i][j] + "]" + "  "); 
                } 
            }
           
            System.out.println("\n¿Otra venta? 1=Si, 2=No:) ");
            Venta = Entrada.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Lo he resuelto de la siguiente forma:
do {
                do {
                try
                {continua = false;
            Venta = 1;
                System.out.println(" Cantidad de boletos a comprar:) ");
            compra1 = Entrada.nextInt(); 
            } catch(InputMismatchException ime)
                { System.out.println("");
                    System.err.println("se permiten caracteres numericos");
                    Entrada.next(); continua = true; }
                } while (continua);
            contador1 = 1;
            do {
                System.out.println(" Elija número de butaca:) ");
                Asignacion = Entrada.nextInt();
                error1 = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
                if (Sala1[i][j] == Asignacion) { posicion1 = error1; fila = i;  columna = j; } error1++; } }
                  if (posicion1 >= 1) { Sala1[fila][columna] = 99; }
                else {System.out.println("Butaca restringida");}
                contador1++;
            } while (contador1 <= compra1);
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                System.out.println();
                for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) { System.out.print("[" + Sala1[i][j] + "]" + "  "); } }
           
            System.out.println("\n¿Otra venta? 1=Si, 2=No:) ");
            Venta = Entrada.nextInt();
                   } while (Venta ==1);


[![//Ahora tengo otro problema, si elijo un asiento restringido (el que tiene numero cero) o uno ya asignado, la porción de código que valida no se ejecuta correctamente.][1]][1]
```